# How to persist non-JSON serializable object between flask routes

Tags: python, flask, caching

I need to connect to a Bluetooth LE device, then read and write characteristic values, and finally disconnect from the Bluetooth LE device. I am trying to set up a REST API for performing these steps. Connecting consumes approximately 20 seconds, so I would like to persist the connection, rather than reconnect each time I need to read or write a characteristic value. For brevity, I am only including the Connect and Disconnect steps.

I am using flask and flask_caching in my attempt to persist an object, BLEComm, between calls to ConnectUUT() and DisconnectUUT().

Below is the code I am using. First I call ConnectUUT(), then DisconnectUUT(). DisconnectUUT() is not retrieving the BLEComm object from the cache, so BLEComm is being recreated - this is not what I want.

How do I store a custom object, that is not JSON serializable, such that it persists between calls to REST routes?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import request, jsonify
from waitress import serve

from clsBLEcomm import clsBLEcomm

config = {
    "DEBUG": True,                      
    "CACHE_TYPE": "SimpleCache",
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300 
}

# Create an instance of the Flask class that is the WSGI application.
# The first argument is the name of the application module or package,
# typically __name__ when using a single module.
app = Flask(__name__)

# tell Flask to use the above defined config
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)

# Flask route decorators map urls to functions.
#NOTE:  No error handling or logging going on in here.  I wanted to wait and discuss how you want to handle this.
# ConnectUUT
# Example: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/ConnectUUT?MAC_ID=abcd
@app.route('/api/ConnectUUT', methods=['get'])
async def ConnectUUT():
    global dictCache

    # error if missing required entry
    ErrorResponse = '0: OK'

    BLEComm = cache.get("BLEcomm") # now the cache is available within a view  
    if BLEComm is None: # service hasn't been added to cache or is expired
        BLEComm=clsBLEcomm()

    # Store a reference to the BLEComm object to cache
    cache.set("BLEComm", BLEComm)

    await BLEComm.ConnectUUT(MAC_ID=MAC_ID)

    return ErrorResponse

# DisconnectUUT
# Example: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/DisconnectUUT
@app.route('/api/DisconnectUUT', methods=['get'])
async def DisconnectUUT():
    global dictCache

    # error if missing required entry
    ErrorResponse = '0: OK'

    # Attempt to get the BLEComm object from cache
    BLEComm = cache.get("BLEcomm") # now the cache is available within a view

    if BLEComm is None: # service hasn't been added to cache or is expired
        BLEComm=clsBLEcomm()

    await BLEComm.DisconnectUUT()

    return ErrorResponse


# start the flask app, using waitress
serve(app, port=5000)
```

When running the above code, DisconnectUUT() does not retrieve the BLEComm object from cache. I expected it to retrieve the BLEComm object from cache to allow the function to disconnect from the Bluetooth LE device.

Comment: Pickle is a common solution for storing custom objects in a local disk file.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I have not. Would pickle store a bleak client?

Comment: I believe pickle can store any python object.  I don't know what a bleak client is, so I can't answer specifically.

Comment: When I try pickle, I get the exception, "Cannot serialize socket object" when dumping to the pickle file.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that when you said it was a "client" object.  I don't know that it's possible to serialize an open connection (file/socket/http/whatever).

Comment: So, the real question is, "Is there a mechanism that allows some sort of connection to be opened in one REST route and to be accessed in another REST route?"

Comment: I thought that a REST architecture was a good design decision for this project. Lacking an ability to persist a connection between REST endpoints (re-connecting to a BLE device takes way too long), I am open to suggestions for another architecture - my next choice would be a daemon that the client communicates with using MQTT.

Comment: One option is to initialize a global client object when the app starts, so each route function can access it directly.  But that has its own problems -- connections don't generally like to stay open for hours or days at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257214/discussion-between-hamilton-woods-and-john-gordon).